# ClickOnce not including interop assembly

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, dll, clickonce

I've created serveral in-house applications in Visual Studio that are distributed with ClickOnce. Over the weekend we got a new domain name controller with a new server name. I had to redistribute several of the applications because they used a UNC path (\server\folder\application folder) for distribution. All went well except one.

This one, along with others, uses an Adobe Acrobat DLL to display PDF files. On this one application I get a file IO error because it can't find the interop assembly (System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Acrobat,)

Other odd things with this one are that there is not a release or debug folder under bin. Even if I make changes under the configuration manager it dumps all assemblies in the root of the bin folder. Also, when I publish it creates both an appname.exe file and an appname.application file. The ClickOnce distribution folder has the interop.acrobat.dll file, but it is not being installed.

I'm a little unsure what is going on. Do I need to include the interop.acrobat.dll  when I publish? I don't create new applications a lot and it has been a while since I set up a new ClickOnce distribution.

If I manually copy the outputs (appname.exe and interop assemblies) to the end users computer and launch appname.exe it runs fine.

Greg

Answer (score 1):

I created a new project and imported all forms, classes, and modules from the old project. Signed the ClickOnce manifest and had the same issue with the Adobe PIA. I then switched from .Net 3.5 to .Net 4.5 and the problem went away.

Go figure.

Greg